# Socket in Python over dynamic ip

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I was watching a socket video on python in that video they made a simple client and server file and once the client connects to the server it will send a message to a client this can be done in a local network only because there we are using local host ip address. My question is how do I make one that works over the internet not just on the local network also I have an dynamic ip address. I tried using noip.com to get a hostname server that will automatically update the dynamic ip address but it shows an error when I try to bind it as

**OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context**

server.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind(('chatbotpersonal.ddns.net', 5555))
#here in the video they used 127.0.0.1 as it is for localhost

s.listen()

while True:
    client, address = s.accept()
    print(f'connected to {address}')
    client.send('You are connected'.encode())
    client.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect(('chatbotpersonal.ddns.net', 5555))

message = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print(message.decode())
```

Thank You in advance. I'm new to this socket and networking please bare with me.

Comment: go to whatismyip.org and look at your ip address, then go to your router and set up rules to forward traffic on 5555 to your local pc ... then you can connect how you want ... but in general peer-to-peer type stuff needs some centralized server that basically acts as a middleman (ie most users would not know how to check their ip address let alone setup port forwards on their router

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thank you for the reply but I know that much. I don't think u read it properly I have a dynamic ip adress it changes after some time if I use my current ip i have to change it every time and that's not the solution

Comment: first make it work with your regular non-local ip ... then you should be 99% of the way there for the noip solution... as you will still need to forward the port from your router etc in order to get the noip solution